# Create SQL Server Agent jobs programatically

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-agent

I want to create SQL Server Agent jobs programmatically. I am using the following code, while running it doesn't throw any error but when I check SQL Server Agent I don't see any jobs.

So question 1: is this the right way to create a job in `msdb` from `etgv125p (my database)` database?

When I use `connectionString` with `Initial Catalog=msdb`, I am getting an error

> The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'CreateSQLAgentjobs', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'

Question 2: what type of credentials do I need to have? I am already admin.

Code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string connetionString = "Data Source=SERVER;Initial Catalog=etgv125p;User ID=USER;Password=PASSWORD;Application Name=LOCAL";
    //string connetionString = "Data Source=SERVER;Initial Catalog=msdb;User ID=USER;Password=PASSWORD;Application Name=LOCAL";

    SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

    string job = "Test_Job";
    string command = "Test_StoredProc";
    string serverName = "SERVERNAME";
    string startDate = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
    string startTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString();

    try
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "CreateSQLAgentjobs";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@job", job);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mycommand", command);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@servername", serverName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startdate", startDate);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@starttime", startTime);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Connection = cnn;

        cnn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();   // Error when using msdb connection string.
        cnn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // ignored
    }
}
```

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE CreateSQLAgentjobs 
@job NVARCHAR(128),
@mycommand NVARCHAR(max), 
@servername NVARCHAR(28),
@startdate NVARCHAR(8),
@starttime NVARCHAR(8)
AS
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN

    GRANT EXEC on CreateSQLAgentjobs to PUBLIC
    --1. Add a job
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_job
        @job_name = @job

    --2. Add a job step named process step. This step runs the stored procedure
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep
        @job_name = @job,
        @step_name = N'process step',
        @subsystem = N'TSQL',
        @command = @mycommand

    --3. Schedule the job at a specified date and time
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobschedule @job_name = @job,
        @name = 'MySchedule',
        @freq_type=1,
        @active_start_date = @startdate,
        @active_start_time = @starttime

    --4. Add the job to the SQL Server 
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver
        @job_name =  @job,
        @server_name = @servername
    COMMIT TRAN
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT ERROR_Message(), ERROR_Line();
    ROLLBACK TRAN
END CATCH
```

Comment: Did you try granting execute permission on the stored procedure to yourself, or to public, or any other group that you're a member of?

Comment: @TabAlleman I've updated my stored proc. Are you talking about this way? If so, I'm still getting the same error. Please correct me if I am doing something wrong here.

Comment: I'm talking about `GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.CreateSQLAgentjobs TO YourLoginName`

Comment: @TabAlleman  I tried that too but same error.

Comment: You don't put the GRANT statement IN the stored procedure code, as you have done in your example.  Just open a window in SSMS and execute the GRANT statement by itself.

Comment: @TabAlleman Didn't work. I am looking at this link (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=43v_5k4kfoU) which has similar store proc like mine but I am not sure why mine is not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102278/discussion-between-robinhood-and-tab-alleman).

Answer (score 1):

for the error you are seeing for The EXECUTE permission was denied.... please open SSMS and execute the following code on a query tab:

```
GRANT EXEC on CreateSQLAgentjobs to PUBLIC
```

and remove it from the proc