# Pass Parameter to Job which calls a stored procedure with the parameter provided?

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure called `sp_Rep_QTR` which expects the following parameters: `@stardate, @endate`.

Now what I want to do is the following: create a job which will `EXEC` the `sp_Rep_QTR` at a time (`@active_start_time`) provided and pass the `@stardate, @endate` parameters to the stored procedure.

The `@stardate, @endate` parameters will be passed to a stored procedure which will create the job - these are passed from a web page.

Comment: Are you asking how to create a agent job using T-SQL?

Comment: This may be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35135862/create-sql-server-agent-jobs-programatically